# wxpython custom text entry dialog

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I am trying to do a text entry dialog, but I don´t want to use the built-in method. I´m doing pretty well , the only problem is that is the buttons are displaying perfectly, but **the text entry is Hidden**.

Where is the issue?

```
class RouteWindow(wx.Dialog):
   def __init__(self):
    super(RouteWindow, self).__init__(None)
    self.DialogUI()
    self.SetSize((200, 250))
    self.SetTitle("Specify Route...")

   def DialogUI(self):
    pan = wx.Panel(self)
    vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL) 
    dial_box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    dial_text = wx.StaticText(pan, label = "Route :")
    dial_box.Add(dial_text,0,wx.ALL,5)
    dial_camp = wx.TextCtrl(pan)
    dial_box.Add(dial_camp,wx.EXPAND)
    vbox.Add(dial_box,wx.ALIGN_CENTER|wx.TOP, border = 4)
    opt_box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    opt_close = wx.Button(self, label = "Close")
    opt_ok = wx.Button(self, label = "OK" )
    opt_box.Add(opt_ok)
    opt_box.Add(opt_close, flag =  wx.LEFT, border = 5)
    vbox.Add(opt_box, flag = wx.ALIGN_CENTER|wx.BOTTOM, border = 4)
    self.SetSizer(vbox)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your layout is wrong ... you need to add pan

```
def DialogUI(self):
    pan = wx.Panel(self)
    vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL) 
    dial_box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    dial_text = wx.StaticText(pan, label = "Route :")
    dial_box.Add(dial_text,0,wx.ALL,5)
    dial_camp = wx.TextCtrl(pan)
    dial_box.Add(dial_camp,wx.EXPAND)
    pan.SetSizer(dial_box) #<---- set sizer of pan to be dial_box

    vbox.Add(pan,wx.ALIGN_CENTER|wx.TOP, border = 4) #<----add pan to main sizer
    opt_box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    opt_close = wx.Button(self, label = "Close")
    opt_ok = wx.Button(self, label = "OK" )
    opt_box.Add(opt_ok)
    opt_box.Add(opt_close, flag =  wx.LEFT, border = 5)
    vbox.Add(opt_box, flag = wx.ALIGN_CENTER|wx.BOTTOM, border = 4)
    self.SetSizer(vbox)
```

although I dont understand why you wouldnt use the get_text_from_user builtin but meh ... for that matter i dont really understand why you are creating a panel instead of just attachign to self ...

on a side note if you make

```
opt_ok = wx.Button(self,wx.ID_OK )
opt_close = wx.Button(self,wx.ID_CANCEL )
```

you will get some of the behaviour for free (IE return from show modal)